# how to hide/show a div using a media query but not when it's within another div

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm trying to hide a specific div using a media query which is working fine. However, I need it to show when that div is within another specific div. Is this possible. This is the CSS:

```
@media (min-width: 665px) {
.mrbcircle-ipad:not(.link-inside.mrbcircle-ipad) {
position:absolute;
display:none;
}
}
```

so `.mrbcircle-ipad` should be hidden over 665px unless it's within `.link-inside`.

Currently this is showing `.mrbcircle` everywhere so I know it's wrong. How can I fix this?

Thanks
Anthony

Comment: i think you must use only one selector inside :not like this .mrbcircle-ipad:not(.link-insid) {

Comment: Thank you. I've just tried this and it now doesn't show it anywhere.

Comment: Show your html code maybe we can help you

Answer (score 0):

```
@media (min-width: 665px) {
.mrbcircle-ipad {
  position:absolute;
  display:none;
 }
.link-inside .mrbcircle-ipad{
  position relative; 
  display: block;
 }
}
```

Comment: Yes true but it's bsed in his HTML

Answer (score 0):

Use two rules inside the media query: The first to hide it when the viewport is wider than 665px, the second to make it visible if it's inside a certain parent:

```
@media (min-width: 666px) {
  .mrbcircle-ipad {
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
  }
  .link-inside .mrbcircle-ipad{
    display: block;
  }
}
```